# How to constantly monitor user input in a WinForm application

Tags: c#, input

In my WinForm application I need a login system to enable/disable some functionality. This login is made using a magnetic card readed by a USB card reader that works in Keyboard emulation.
If I force the user to select a textbox and then swipe the card I can receive the code in the textbox and then process it, but how can I do if I want to get this code in any moment also if a textbox is not the current selected control?

I'm thinking about a background console application just to receive the code whit Console.ReadLine() but it doesn't work when I'm focused on my winform.

Comment: That's not how security cards work. You are describing POS scanners, which have 0 security and protection against duplication - that's why they were discontinued and replaced by Pin & Chip! Cloning them is trivial. Smart card authentication is supported at the OS level since 2000. It has nothing to do with keyboards, the security subsystem itself recognizes the card, its certificates and validates it. The relevant APIs can be used to detect the presence or absence of the card

Comment: Most scanners appear as serial devices. The more expensive ones own APIs while the cheaper ones emulate keyboards. You may be able to disable the keyboard emulation and use the serial interface to listen for data

Comment: your comments are off-topic. Andrea has some device and needs to create proper software. that's all. your comments gives nothing to find solution. it's not thread about security.

Comment: @MaciejS. are you sure? Your own answer is the "read from serial/driver" case. Most likely the card reader supports this through configuration. The keyboard emulation problem is common with barcode scanners too. As for security `I need a login system to enable/disable some functionality` *login* is already supported at the OS level. A card reader that works as a keyboard is too weak for this. It's OK for membership/loyalty cards though, probably combined with a password

Comment: @Andrea a common way to solve this with barcode scanners without a serial mode is to enable [Form.KeyPreview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview?view=netframework-4.7.2) to allow the *form* to catch keyboard events before they reach the controls. The scanner can be configured to send a specific character sequence before each string to allow the application to detect which events come from the scanner and which ones come from the actual keyboard

Comment: @Andrea on WPF you can use a [routed input event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview#wpf-input-events) to handle the [PreviewKeyDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.contentelement.previewkeydown?view=netframework-4.7.2) event at the form level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a concept from my own similiar app (with fingerprint reader):

1. Create Windows service app which will monitor your USB card reader device;
2. Link this service with some DLL library in your WinForms app;
3. If any activity will be detected, call proper method in linked DLL library and do all requested operations.

Comment: The OP is describing a POS scanner like those used to scan *barcodes*. That's where the reference to keyboards and text boxes comes from. The cheapest models emulate keyboards, they don't have specialized drivers. I suspect the card in question is a loyalty card

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos But there is no difference between my app and requested app - my device is connected via USB as well as magnetic card reader. I have to catch USB activity as well as Andrea. I have to store it in some type of object, and he in string... What's the difference in general concept?

Comment: In that case, there's no difference between a USB keyboard and a USB webcam. In reality, the drivers of each device do all the work. Your code never interacts with the USB port. In your case, the driver is the one that authenticates the biometric data and tells you who the user is. In the POS scanner case, the driver emulates a that sends keystrokes to the application.

Comment: Driver tells me nothing - it's sending some very long alpha-numeric strings packed in some object. I have to catch it. My task is to identify user by finding  user in database that corresponds to this data. That's all. By the way - do you know what does it mean "concept"? BTW you don't know what kind of device I got so why do you even discuss about that?